# Pyspark read jdbc giving errors . How to fix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, amazon-rds

I am connecting to RDS MySQL using JDBC in pyspark . I have tried almost everything that I found on Stackoverflow for debugging but still, i am unable to make it work .

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", mysql_jar) \
            .master("local[*]").appName("PySpark_MySQL_test").getOrCreate()
df= spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://hostname.amazonaws.com:1150/dbname?user=user_name&password=password") \
            .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "table_name").load()
```

I have tried using the same connection details in pymysql library of python it connects and brings back the result.
But here I getting the below error and am unable to solve it.

---

```py
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProvider$.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Did you check that your connection works with `pymysql` from the driver machine or also from the worker machines (if any exist)?

Comment: @werner   i tried using pymysql and pyspark on same machine.

Comment: So after trying everything , i tried with the latest jar  : `mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar` and it worked . I dont know why it happened . I had tried with  `mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar`

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issues.Now it is worked.The core reason is spark use master node to connect mysql and use work nodes to execute task.So you can connect mysql while raise communication error.Based on this theory,you can open the security rules on mysql to let all spark node can connect to mysql

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here for an answer using Docker give the below solution a try.
use the below configuration

```
source_df = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
        url='jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/superset?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true',
        driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        dbtable='table',
        user='root',
        password='root').load()
```

I have tried the host with `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and even the `IPAddress`  from docker inspect but didn't work then changed it to  `host.docker.internal` and it worked.